# Is there any way to automatize file export operation?

Tags: macros, coreldraw

Recently I'm using CorelDraw to create icons for my android application, and I have a little problem. Each icon has to be exported as a png to 6 different sizes, and it is quite annoying to export each icon 6 times. Is there any way to create a macro or other automation stuff that will do for example 6 exports of a file to a dedicated location? All the export settings besides the width and height are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses the `ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap` command to export something as a PNG.

[Here is someone over at the corel draw community calling it](http://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x5/f/544/t/25184).

The resolutions are passed as arguments to `ExportBitmap`.  Make a macro that hard codes 6 sizes and exports them to slightly different filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You may not find a free macro as your request on the net. You should ask it to macro developer as it's custom macro.

I got idea for this request.

- Macro interface loaded :

  - a text box for entering png name (or auto numbering)
  - text boxes for prefix and suffix name (6x)
  - auto filled file path for each of 6
  - a button for execute
- Select Icon, then click the button. The selected icon will exported to predefined folder with specific name.

i.e :

- Prefix_Icon1_48x48.png
- Prefix_Icon1_72x72.png
- Prefix_Icon1_96x96.png

and so on.

If all your ison is as ONE PAGE only, the macro will available exported each icon as 6 sizes png, WITH auto filenaming function.

Yup, I think it would be as commercial macro.